# Are the g++4.3 and g++4.7 series ABI compatible?

Tags: g++, abi

Also if I compile a piece of code with c++11 flag will it be compatible with another code compiled without c++11 flag? Where can I find the compatibility list?

Comment: 4.7 changes are [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html). 4.7.2 should be *mostly* compatible with 4.3 on *most* platforms, in C++11 or C++03 mode. 4.7.\[01\] are *not* compatible in C++11 mode.